# How is the correct way to send a json serializer

Tags: python, django

I am practicing with serializers and I find an error because I want to send json from my queryset and the error it generates is context must be a dict rather than JsonResponse, I read the documentation and it says that setting the safe parameter to false allows sending any object serializer:

This is my view:

```
class TypeTaskListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'tasks/type_task.html'
    queryset = TypeTask.objects.all().order_by('-pk')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        data = serializers.serialize('json', context['object_list'])

        return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

Comment: `get_context_data` is supposed to *return a dict*. A dict of values which will be available in the template. If you want to have JSON data available in the template, fine, then put it as a string into that dict which you return from `get_context_data`. Why are you trying to return a `JsonResponse` from it? Do you really need a template view there?!

Comment: I had not realized that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not return a `JsonResponse` out of a `get_context_data`, the code contract assumes that `get_context_data` returns a dictionary.

You will need to override the [**`.render_to_response(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin.render_to_response):

```
from json import loads as jloads

class TypeTaskListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'tasks/type_task.html'
    queryset = TypeTask.objects.order_by('-pk')

    def render_to_response(self, context, **kwargs):
        data = serializers.serialize('json', context['object_list'])
        return JsonResponse({'data': jloads(data)})
```

That being said, it looks like you are constructing an API view, in that case you probably better work with the [*Django Rest Framework*](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) which has logic to implement API views, viewsets, serializers, permissions, etc.

---

> **Note**: In 2008, [Phil Haack discovered a way to obtain data from the outer JSON array](https://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx/).
> While most browser have implemented countermeasures, it is still better to use a
> JSON object as "envelope" of the data. That is why a
> [**`JsonResponse`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)
> by default does not allow something else than a `dict` as outer object. It might
> thus better to use a dictionary and keep `safe=True` on `True`.

Comment: I didn't know about django rest framework, and if I'm making an api, I'm going to read the django rest framework documentation and practice with it, thank you very much